# how to grab large xml response using ksoap

Tags: android, ksoap

I am using the ksoap library to consume .net webservice. One of the request returns a very larger xml response.The thing is  ksoap shows only partial response.But the wireshark trace shows xml response as  sequence of TCP segments which represent the bulk XML.

any idea to grab full xml response?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify HttpTransportSE.java file for saving WS response directly in a xml file. Then you can parse it as you prefer. Last ksoap release (3.0.0) has got a method for saving response in a file if you don't want modify java class.